# Sending 'self' to an object

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I've got an IBOutlet and an IBAction connected to an AppController Class.
When a button is clicked, it creates an instance of another class (CData) with a message to calculate a string. My problem was that I wanted the IBOutlet to be reachable from within the CData object.

I've solved it by including `self` in the message and created an update method to the IBOutlet in AppController.

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
CData *myData = [[CData alloc] init];
[myData calculateString:self];
[myData release];
}
```

And in `calculateString` I've done the following:

```
- (void)calculateString:(id)parent
{
   [parent updateTextLog:@"Print data..."];
}
```

It works like a charm. 
But my question is, as I'm trying to familiar myself to Obj-C and Cocoa, if this is a good way to solve the problem, or if there's another way?

It's just a proof of concept, as I very well know that I could have just let `calculateString` return a value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not solve the problem in this way.

If the `CData` class has to update the view in some way, then you should be doing it inside the `IBAction` method, or considering it as a Model class in the MVC pattern, and having it generate a `NSNotifcation` that the view can observe.

The former way is easiest:

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{
    CData *myData = [[CData alloc] init];
    ReturnValueType someReturnValue = [myData calculateString:self];
    [someObject someMethod:someReturnValue];
    [myData release];
}
```

This reduces coupling since the `CData` (Model) class doesn't need to know about the existance of any Views or Controllers.

Comment: Hmm, as I want to run some calculation in a separate thread and not do  a print immediately. NSNotification would be the way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: Personally, I feel that notifications are appropriate only for events that affect multiple layers and objects in the code. If it's something like a delayed calculation, or a simple callback, delegation is typically more appropriate: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern

Answer (score 1):

If we were to follow the MVC architecture, and Cocoa Touch does, the model layer should be completely abstracted from view layer. In this case, giving your CData class access to an IBOutlet violates this principle - assuming that CData is a model-type class.
Like you said, one way of going about it is to return something from `-calculateString`. This may seem like more code but does not limit the reusability of your model class.

Comment: The way he's done it, he gives CData access to the controller not the view.

Comment: IMO, the problem is that he is passing a pointer to the controller. So technically, the CData can access view classes through the pointer. Avoiding passing pointers to classes of different layers is what MVC is all about.